# Determine if a CGContextRef points to a CGBitmapContext

Tags: core-graphics, cgbitmapcontext

I was wondering how to ask an "isKindOfClass" to a CGContextRef in order to determine if it's a standard CGContext or a CGBitmapContext.

I can't find a way to determine it :/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you come up with any way?

Comment: nope :( therefore I added a level of abstraction to my code (i.e different method names)